# Integrate Keycloak Identities with local .NET application

Tags: .net, keycloak, openid

I am using Keycloak as an Identity Provider to manage, authentication and authorize all users via Openid in a .NET web application.

However, I am not clear about the proper integration of these users in my .NET application. Should I check after each login if the users is in the local .NET identity database and create the users if they don't exist or how do I handle them? Because I need to refence users in my database for other data.

And if I create them, what shall I store in the .NET application's database? Since some data can change the only thing which will not change on Keycloak is the users uuid.

Comment: Would you like to [use Keycloak as your identity provider](https://nikiforovall.github.io/aspnetcore/dotnet/2022/08/24/dotnet-keycloak-auth.html)? Or use another? I have some confusion.

Comment: @Chen As I wrote I am already using Keycloak as an identity provider. The question is how those users from and IP are integrated into your users database, since they are referenced throughout your local application.